# How to find an element with a given ID in a set of DOM elements?

Tags: jquery

I have some divs in a jquery set, called set$,  that have all been moved together, and I want to be able now to UNDO the move.  Before I did the move I cloned set$ with:

```
set_before_move$ = set$.clone()
```

After the move, the `set$` members are all moved and the `set_before_move$` members should have the original offset.    My thought to undo the move was to go through `set$` and for each member

1. get the id
2. find the element with that id in `set_before_move$`
3. pull the offset from the `set_before_move$` member
4. apply that offset in the `set$` member

The code I have looks like:

```
var off;
set$.each(function () {
   moved_id = $(this).attr('id');  // get the id of this element
   unmoved_el$ = set_before_move$.([id=moved_id]); // find element in set_before_move$
   off = unmoved_el$.offset();    // get its offset
   $(this).offset(off);   // put the offset into the set$ member
});
```

But it doesn't like the square brackets. Does someone see the right way to do  this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, to reduce the jQuery object `set_before_move$` to a set of a single element with `moved_id`.

For example:

```
var moved_id = 'some-id'; 
unmoved_el$  = set_before_move$.filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id') == moved_id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set true:

```
set_before_move$ = set$.clone(true)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not getting the offset values of the original div. I opened a new question here on it, with a jsfiddle, if you want to look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397899/clone-not-getting-top-left-values-of-original-div