# Clone not getting top/left values of original div

Tags: jquery

I'm cloning a div here - http://jsfiddle.net/ncA6c/ -  and I don't understand why the clone didn't pick up the top/left values of the original box offset.  Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

```
$(function(){   
    boxClone$ = $('#box').clone(true);
    console.log("box offset = ",  $('#box').offset());
    console.log("boxClone offset = ",  boxClone$.offset());

});
```

Comment: The cloned element is not in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @undefined said The cloned element is not on the DOM.

You need to insert it at the DOM. Then only you could get the offset.

```
$(function(){   
    boxClone$ = $('#box').clone(true).appendTo('body');
    console.log("box offset = ",  $('#box').offset());
    console.log("boxClone offset = ",  boxClone$.offset());

});
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncA6c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

since `id` is unique, you need to clone it with new id and append it somewhere.

```
$(function(){   
    $('#box').clone().prop({'id':"newId"}).appendTo('body');
    console.log("box offset = ",  $('#box').offset());
    console.log("boxClone offset = ", $('#newId').offset());
});
```

and add the css too

```
div#box, div#newId { /* ... */ }
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kqVF/)